# Linux command for rmdir and mklink?

Tags: linux

All,

What is the rmdir and mklink command for linux platform ?
For windows it is - `rmdir /S/Q` for rmdir and `mklink /D/J` for mklink.

How to write similar in Linux.

Thanks :)

Comment: `rm -rf`  is for recursive deletion on linux. To create symbolic link - `ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink`

Comment: @npocmaka Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well to answer

## **What is the rmdir and mklink command for linux platform ?**

1. There is no **`mklink`** command available in Linux however an equivalent command **`ln`** serves the purpose.
2. Going By the man pages **`rmdir`** in Linux removes empty directories.

For windows it is - rmdir /S/Q for rmdir and mklink /D/J for mklink.

## **How to write similar in Linux ?**

1. **`rmdir`** -  Removes a directory provided it's empty, However If directory is not empty then Using **`rm`** is wise

**Remove empty directory :**

> $ rmdir path/to/directory

**Remove directories Recursively (useful for nested dirs) :**

> $ rmdir -p path/to/directory

**Remove files from a location :**

> $ rm  path/to/file  path/to/another/file

**Recursively remove a directory & all it's subdirectories :**

> $ rm -r path/to/directory

**Force Remove a Directory, withour prompting for confirmation or showing any error messages :**

> $ rm -rf path/to/directory

**Intercatively Remove multiple Files, with a prompt before every removal :**

> $ rm -i  file  another_file  another_file

2. **`ln`** - Creates links to files and folders

**Create a hard link to file :**

> $ ln path/to/file/to/hardlink

**Create a symbolic link to file of folder :**

> $ ln -s path/to/file/to/symlink

**Overwrite an existing symbolic link to point to another file :**

> $ ln -sf  path/to/new/file  path/to/symlink

NOTE - You cannot use `ln` to create hard links for directories.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thanks :)

Comment: What is the use of ```/D/J``` in mklink and ```/S/Q``` in remove directory ?

Comment: For [mklink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html), **`/D creates directory symobolic (not hard) link`** and **`/J creates a directory Junction`** .For [rmdir](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) **`/S removes files and folders recursively`** `same as -r in rm` command and **`/Q means Quiet`** ie. don't ask for confirmation (y/n) before removing`